# Integrate Gaussian pdf over Mahalanobis distance set of different Gaussian pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, mahalanobis-distance

**Question**: Let $f_X(\boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol\mu_a,S_a)$ be a $d$-dimensional Gaussian probability density function (pdf), let $\tilde{f}_X(\boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol\mu_b,S_b)$ be a different $d$-dimensional Gaussian pdf and let $R=\left\{\boldsymbol x| \sqrt{(\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol \mu_b)S_b^{-1}(\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol \mu_b)^T} \le \varepsilon\right\}$ be the set of points that have at most a Mahalanobis distance of $\varepsilon$ from $\boldsymbol{\mu}_b$. What is $$F_{X}(\boldsymbol x \in R)=\int_{\boldsymbol x\in R} f_X(\boldsymbol x| \boldsymbol \mu_a, S_a) d\boldsymbol x\quad?$$ In other words, what is the probability measure of the overlap between two Gaussians if we cut off one of them at a certain Mahalanobis distance?

**Background**: A similar term occurs in an unsolved non-convex optimization problem I am studying. I would guess that the solution is well-known and involves concepts like the non-central Chi-squared distribution and/or the Bhattacharyya coefficient.

**What I have tried so far**: For the simple case $f_X=\tilde{f}_X$ we get the well-known result $$F_X(\boldsymbol x\in R)=\tilde{F}_X(\boldsymbol x\in R)=\chi^2_d(\varepsilon^2)$$ where $\chi_d^2$ is the chi-squared distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom centered at $\sum \mu^2$. If $f_X\neq\tilde{f_X}$, then it seems to me that the solution would involve rescaling via an eigendecomposition of $S_a$ and $S_b$ to "adjust" $\chi^2_d$ accordingly, but I don't see how.
Also, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290543/integrate-gaussian-pdf-over-another-gaussian-to-get-probability-of-imprecise-da) which is similar but does not include $R$ and is restricted to the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: I think it may not be possible to obtain some closed form solution, as it is equivalent to finding probability of standard Gaussian vector being inside some elipse. In general, such region is not symmetric around 0, which makes integrals (almost) impossible to compute explicitely.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei Regarding symmetry, I was thinking that maybe it helps to shift $R$ (or maybe $f_X$) to the origin by subtracting an appropriate vector. That way, the integral would at least be symmetrical around the origin (but not necessarily around $\boldsymbol \mu_a$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long to comment.

First, observe that if $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{0}, I\right)$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix), then $A \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{b} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{b}, A A^T\right)$, and vice versa, if $\boldsymbol{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, S)$, then $S^{-1/2} \left(\boldsymbol{Y} - \boldsymbol{\mu}\right) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{0}, I\right)$, where $S^{-1/2} = \left(\sqrt{S}\right)^{-1}$ is the inverse of matrix square root of $S$ (which is defined according to the general theory of function on symmetric matrices).

Notice that $$\left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)^T S_b^{-1} \left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right) =
\left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)^T S_b^{-1/2} S_b^{-1/2} \left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right) = \\ =
\left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)^T \left(S_b^{-1/2}\right)^T S_b^{-1/2} \left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right) = \left\|S_b^{-1/2} \left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)\right\|^2,$$
where $\left\| \;\cdot\;\right\|$ denotes Euclidean norm, so
$R_{\varepsilon} = \left\{\boldsymbol{x} :  \left\|S_b^{-1/2} \left(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)\right\| \leq \varepsilon\right\}$. Then
for $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_a, S_a\right)$
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\boldsymbol{X} \in R_{\varepsilon}\right) = 
\mathbb{P}\left(
\left\|S_b^{-1/2} \left(\boldsymbol{X} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)\right\| \leq \varepsilon\right) = \\ =
\mathbb{P}\left(
\left\|S_b^{-1/2} \left(S_a^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y} + \boldsymbol{\mu}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)\right\| \leq \varepsilon\right) = 
\mathbb{P}\left(
\left\|S_b^{-1/2} S_a^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y} + S_b^{-1/2}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)\right\| \leq \varepsilon\right),
$$
where $\boldsymbol{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{0}, I\right)$.
Let's introduce new vector $\boldsymbol{W} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\nu}, \Sigma\right)$, where
$\boldsymbol{\nu} = S_b^{-1/2}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b\right)$ and $\Sigma = S_b^{-1/2} S_a^{1/2} \left(S_b^{-1/2} S_a^{1/2}\right)^T = S_b^{-1/2} S_a^{1/2} S_a^{1/2} S_b^{-1/2} = 
S_b^{-1/2} S_a S_b^{-1/2}$.

So, given problem is equivalent to calculating $\mathbb{P}\left(\left\|\boldsymbol{W} \right\| \leq \varepsilon\right)$ for some non-standard Gaussian vector. It gets tricky even for 1D Gaussian. It this case for $X \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\mu_a, s_a\right)$ and some $\mu_b, s_b > 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$W \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s_b}} (\mu_a - \mu_b), \frac{s_a}{s_b} \right)$, which leads to $$\mathbb{P}\left(|W| \leq \varepsilon\right) = F_W (\varepsilon) - F_W(-\varepsilon) = \\ =
\Phi\left(
\frac{\varepsilon - \frac{1}{\sqrt{s_b}} (\mu_a - \mu_b)}{\sqrt{\frac{s_a}{s_b}}}\right) - 
\Phi\left(
\frac{-\varepsilon - \frac{1}{\sqrt{s_b}} (\mu_a - \mu_b)}{\sqrt{\frac{s_a}{s_b}}}\right) = \\ =
\Phi \left(\frac{\varepsilon \sqrt{s_b} - (\mu_a - \mu_b)}{\sqrt{s_a}}\right) - \Phi \left(\frac{-\varepsilon \sqrt{s_b} - (\mu_a - \mu_b)}{\sqrt{s_a}}\right),$$
where $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2/2} \mathrm{d} t$.
As one can see, this expression becomes much simpler in case $\mu_a = \mu_b$.

But as I mentioned in comments, I don't think it's possible to obtain some closed form solution in multidimensional case (however, if $\boldsymbol{\mu}_a = \boldsymbol{\mu}_b$, things may get a bit simpler).

---

EDIT: for $\boldsymbol{W} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\nu}, \Sigma\right)$ we can write
$
\left\|\boldsymbol{W} \right\|^2 = \left\|\Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y}  + \boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2
$ for $\boldsymbol{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{0}, I\right)$. Let $\left<\cdot, \cdot \right>$ denote standard dot product, then
$$
\left\|\boldsymbol{W} \right\|^2 = \left<\Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y}  + \boldsymbol{\nu}, \Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y}  + \boldsymbol{\nu}\right> = \left<\Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y}, \Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y} \right> + 2 \left<\Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{\nu}\right> + \left<\boldsymbol{\nu}, \boldsymbol{\nu} \right> = \\ = 
\left<\Sigma \boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{Y} \right> + 2 \left<\Sigma^{1/2} \boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{\nu}\right> + \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2
$$
As $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is symmetric PSD matrix, $\Sigma^{1/2} = Q \Lambda Q^T$ for some orthogonal $Q$ and diagonal $\Lambda$, and
$\Sigma = Q \Lambda^2 Q^T.$ So, continuing previous equalities,
$$
\left\|\boldsymbol{W} \right\|^2 = \left<Q \Lambda^2 Q^T \boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{Y} \right> + 2 \left<Q \Lambda Q^T \boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{\nu}\right> + \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2 = \\ =
\left<\Lambda^2 Q^T \boldsymbol{Y}, Q^T \boldsymbol{Y} \right> + 2 \left<\Lambda Q^T \boldsymbol{Y}, Q^T\boldsymbol{\nu}\right> + \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2.
$$
As standard Gaussian distribution is spherically symmetric,
$Q^T \boldsymbol{Y}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}$ have equal distributions ($Q^T \boldsymbol{Y} \overset{d}{=} \boldsymbol{Y}$), so
$$
\left\|\boldsymbol{W} \right\|^2 \overset{d}{=}
\left<\Lambda^2 \boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{Y} \right> + 2 \left<\Lambda \boldsymbol{Y}, Q^T\boldsymbol{\nu}\right> + \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2 = \\ =
\sum_{i} \lambda_i^2 \boldsymbol{Y}_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i} \lambda_i \left(Q^T\boldsymbol{\nu}\right)_i \boldsymbol{Y}_i + \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2, 
$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th diagonal element of $\Lambda$. Each $\boldsymbol{Y}_i^2$ follows $\chi^2_1$ distribution and $2 \sum_{i} \lambda_i \left(Q^T\boldsymbol{\nu}\right)_i \boldsymbol{Y}_i + \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2$ is Gaussian with mean $\left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2$ and variance $4 \left\|\Lambda Q^T\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2$.

EDIT: what I've written before about [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) is not applicable, since gaussian term is not independent from chi-squared ones.

> So, $\left\|\boldsymbol{W} \right\|^2$ follows [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) $\tilde{\chi}^2\left(\boldsymbol{w}, \boldsymbol{k}, \boldsymbol{\lambda}, m, s\right)$ with $$ \boldsymbol{w}_i = \lambda_i^2, \; \boldsymbol{k}_i = 1, \; \boldsymbol{\lambda}_i = 0, \; m = \left\|\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2, \; s = 4 \left\|\Lambda Q^T\boldsymbol{\nu}\right\|^2. $$

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. I am wondering if we can't somehow represent $\mathbb{P}(\|\boldsymbol W\| \le \varepsilon)$ via a non-standard chi-squared distribution similar to how it was done in the [standard case](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Cumulative_function_n_dimensional_Gaussians_12.2013.pdf)

Comment: @mto_19 I added some explanation about so-called generalized chi-squared distribution.